# Determining the range of $6^n+ 6^{-n} +3^n +3^{-n}+2$

Tags: functions, relations

> I have to solve for range of the function $$6^n+ 6^{-n} +3^n +3^{-n}+2$$

The textbook solves it as 
$$\left(\sqrt{6^n} -\sqrt{ 6^{-n}} \right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{3^n} -\sqrt{ 3^{-n}} \right)^2 +6 \tag{1}$$ 
i.e., $$(a-b)^2+(a-b)^2$$ 
which will always be greater than $6$, so the range is $(6,\infty)$ (since other two terms are squared). But, if we take 
$$\left(\sqrt{6^n} +\sqrt{ 6^{-n}} \right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{3^n} +\sqrt{ 3^{-n}} \right)^2 +2 \tag{2}$$ 
or $$\left(\sqrt{6^n} +\sqrt{ 6^{-n}} \right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{3^n} +\sqrt{ 3^{-n}} \right)^2 +2 \tag{3}$$
instead of $(1)$, we get that the range is $(-2,\infty)$ or $( 2,\infty)$, respectively.

> So, how do we know what range is correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I'm confused with your question. How are you able to say that the range of $(a+b)^2 + (a+b)^2$ or $(a-b)^2 + (a-b)^2$ has a range of $(-2,\infty)$ and $(2,\infty)$? For both expressions, you're adding the squares of $2$ values so, for real numbers, the sums must both be non-negative. Also, among all possible values of $a$ and $b$, for the first one, $a = -b$ gives $0$ and, for the second one, $a = b$ gives $0$. Thus, the range is $(0,\infty)$ for both.

Comment: thats the substitution i did like tge textbook did ie re writing the function as  (√6ⁿ -√ 6⁻ⁿ )² + (√3ⁿ -√ 3⁻ⁿ )² +6 what i ment to ask was why cant we take   (√6ⁿ +√ 6⁻ⁿ )² + (√3ⁿ +√ 3⁻ⁿ )² -2 or  (√6ⁿ +√ 6⁻ⁿ )² + (√3ⁿ -√ 3⁻ⁿ )² +2   ?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I misread your question to think you were indicating something else. I now see what you were getting at.

Comment: i guess i did wrote it a bit confusing,sorry

Comment: The range is $[6,\infty)$, not $(6,\infty)$, because putting $n=0$ gives a value of $6$. By the way, your question implies that $n$ ranges over the reals; but it is usual to reserve the letter $n$ to refer to integers. $x$ would be a better choice. (And if you really did mean to refer to integers, then the range is not an interval at all, but a sequence of isolated points.)

Answer (score 2):

If you'll take $$3^n+3^{-n}+6^n+6^{-n}+2=\left(\sqrt3^n+\sqrt3^{-n}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt6^n+\sqrt6^{-n}\right)^2-2\geq-2,$$ but the equality does not occur.

But in the following writing 
 $$3^n+3^{-n}+6^n+6^{-n}+2=\left(\sqrt3^n-\sqrt3^{-n}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt6^n-\sqrt6^{-n}\right)^2+6\geq6$$ the equality occurs for $n=0,$ which says that $6$ is a minimal value.

Comment: sorry but i dont understand why not?

Comment: @kay Because for the equality occurring we need $\sqrt3^n+\sqrt3^{-n}=0,$ which is impossible.

Comment: did you mean $3^{-n}$ where you typed $2^{-n}$ ?

Comment: @J. W. Tanner Thank you!

Comment: ok i get it now thnx

Answer (score 1):

Note that:
$$6^n+ 6^{-n} +3^n +3^{-n}+2=\left(\sqrt{6^n} -\sqrt{ 6^{-n}} \right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{3^n} -\sqrt{ 3^{-n}} \right)^2 +6 \ \ \text{(textbook)}\\
6^n+ 6^{-n} +3^n +3^{-n}+2=\left(\sqrt{6^n} +\sqrt{ 6^{-n}} \right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{3^n} +\sqrt{ 3^{-n}} \right)^2 \overbrace{\require{cancel}\cancel{\color{red}+}}^{-} 2\ \ \text{(yours)}\\
$$

Note that by AM-GM:
$$x+\frac1x\ge 2, x>0,$$
the equality occurs for $x=1$.

Hence:
$$6^n+6^{-n}\ge 2, 3^n+3^{-n}\ge 2,\\
\sqrt{6^n}+\sqrt{6^{-n}}\ge 2,\sqrt{3^n}+\sqrt{3^{-n}}\ge 2,$$
the equality in each of the four inequalities occurs for $n=0$.

Thus, your method must be:
$$\left(\sqrt{6^n} +\sqrt{ 6^{-n}} \right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{3^n} +\sqrt{ 3^{-n}} \right)^2 -2 \ge 6,$$
the equality occurs for $n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Because

\begin{align*}
&\color{red}{\left(\sqrt{6^n} -\sqrt{ 6^{-n}} \right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{3^n} -\sqrt{ 3^{-n}} \right)^2 +6} \\&=(\sqrt{6^n})^2-2\sqrt{6^n}\sqrt{ 6^{-n}}+(\sqrt{ 6^{-n}})^2+(\sqrt{3^n})^2-2\sqrt{3^n}\sqrt{ 3^{-n}}+(\sqrt{ 3^{-n}})^2 +6\\
&= 6^n-2\sqrt{6^n 6^{-n}}+6^{-n}+3^n-2\sqrt{3^n 3^{-n}}+ 3^{-n}+6\\
&= 6^n-2\sqrt{6^{n-n}}+6^{-n}+3^n-2\sqrt{3^{n-n}}+ 3^{-n}+6\\
&= 6^n-2\sqrt{6^{0}}+6^{-n}+3^n-2\sqrt{3^{0}}+ 3^{-n}+6\\
&= 6^n-2\sqrt{1}+6^{-n}+3^n-2\sqrt{1}+ 3^{-n}+6\\
&= 6^n-2+6^{-n}+3^n-2+ 3^{-n}+6\\
&= 6^n+6^{-n}+3^n+ 3^{-n}+6-2-2\\
&= 6^n+6^{-n}+3^n+ 3^{-n}+6-4\\
&\color{magenta} =\color{red}{6^n+ 6^{-n} +3^n +3^{-n}+2}
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\left(\sqrt{6^n} +\sqrt{ 6^{-n}} \right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{3^n} +\sqrt{ 3^{-n}} \right)^2 +2} &=6^n+2+6^{-n}+3^n+2+3^{-n}+2
\\&=6^n+6^{-n}+3^n+3^{-n}+6
\\&\color{magenta}  \neq \color{red}{6^n+ 6^{-n} +3^n +3^{-n}+2}
\end{align*}

This means:

If 
$$\color{red}{\left(\sqrt{6^n} -\sqrt{ 6^{-n}} \right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{3^n} -\sqrt{ 3^{-n}} \right)^2 +6} = \color{red}{6^n+ 6^{-n} +3^n +3^{-n}+2}$$ 
and
$$\color{blue}{\left(\sqrt{6^n} +\sqrt{ 6^{-n}} \right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{3^n} +\sqrt{ 3^{-n}} \right)^2 +2} \neq \color{red}{6^n+ 6^{-n} +3^n +3^{-n}+2},$$
then
$$ \color{blue}{\left(\sqrt{6^n} +\sqrt{ 6^{-n}} \right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{3^n} +\sqrt{ 3^{-n}} \right)^2 +2} \neq \color{red}{\left(\sqrt{6^n} -\sqrt{ 6^{-n}} \right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{3^n} -\sqrt{ 3^{-n}} \right)^2 +6} $$

But

$$ \color{red}{\left(\sqrt{6^n} +\sqrt{ 6^{-n}} \right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{3^n} +\sqrt{ 3^{-n}} \right)^2 -2} = \color{red}{6^n+ 6^{-n} +3^n +3^{-n}+2} $$

and

$$ \color{red}{\left(\sqrt{6^n} +\sqrt{ 6^{-n}} \right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{3^n} +\sqrt{ 3^{-n}} \right)^2 -2} =  \color{red}{\left(\sqrt{6^n} -\sqrt{ 6^{-n}} \right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{3^n} -\sqrt{ 3^{-n}} \right)^2 +6}$$

The range of (or the values given by the following expression for $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$) $$\color{red}{6^n+ 6^{-n} +3^n +3^{-n}+2}$$ can be seen better, when you look at $$ \color{red}{\left(\sqrt{6^n} -\sqrt{ 6^{-n}} \right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{3^n} -\sqrt{ 3^{-n}} \right)^2 +6}$$ instead of looking at $$\color{red}{\left(\sqrt{6^n} +\sqrt{ 6^{-n}} \right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{3^n} +\sqrt{ 3^{-n}} \right)^2 -2}$$

Looking at $ \color{red}{\left(\sqrt{6^n} -\sqrt{ 6^{-n}} \right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{3^n} -\sqrt{ 3^{-n}} \right)^2 +6}$ for $n=0$ gives *immediately* a value of $6$. For values $n \geq 1$, we see that $\sqrt{6^n} > \sqrt{ 6^{-n}}$ and $\sqrt{3^n} > \sqrt{ 3^{-n}}$. So we have for $n \geq 1$ that $\sqrt{6^n} - \sqrt{ 6^{-n}}>0$ and $\sqrt{3^n} -\sqrt{ 3^{-n}}> 0$. Also $\left(\sqrt{6^n} -\sqrt{ 6^{-n}} \right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{3^n} -\sqrt{ 3^{-n}} \right)^2 >0$.